# How to show values on line chart after zoom in achartengine?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am using achartengine api to draw line chart on android.
I want to show values on that line chart.
I have used `seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);` but it shows all values, since my chart contains lots of values and because of that values get overwritten upon each other.

So is there a way to show the values so that after zooming the chart it shows values or after some period of time showing the values.

Comment: There is a zoom functionality in AchartEngine

Comment: please give me some example...

Comment: i have applied zoom but on zoom i want to show values on line

Comment: complete example http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Comment: Idea about zooming the chart:- http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Chart/achartengine/org/achartengine/GraphicalView.java.htm